# SAVE CURRENT USERNAME IN TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server-2008

I used the CDC to create a table for logging from the database. For each table, the `INSERT` operation that is performed by the user stores, with the `SYSTEM_USER` command in the triggers defined on the tables, but unfortunately the amount Return is a value defined by the **`SP_CHANGEOWNER`** command.

Comment: Did you try ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), USER_NAME(), SUSER_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME(); ?